# I want to make a scatter graph with two different colours based on words in the columns of a csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatter graph based on a csv file where 1 column has "cat" and one column has "dog".
I want the "cat" points to be red and the "dog" points to be blue.

I tried to add a column that would give cat and dog a binary value but was told the syntax for adding the column was wrong.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Cats and Dogs.csv')

df['Binary Classifier Label'] = 
if df['Classifier Label'] = "Cat":
    df['Binary Classifier Label'] = 1
elseif:
    df['Binary Classifier Label'] = 0
df
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax comes from the first line

I wanted to get a new column in my csv file called Binary Classifier Label that would say 1 for cat and 0 for dogs.

I got a Syntax error in the first line.

Comment: `df['Binary Classifier Label'] = df['Classifier Label'].eq('Cat').astype(int)`